# Saving C922 Pro focus, pan, tilt, and low light compensation settings

Tags: webcam

The Logitech C922 Pro webcam properties such as focus, pan, tilt, and low light compensation do not get saved after restarting the computer so they have to be set each time the computer is restarted. Does anyone know how these settings can be saved permanently? Logitech G Hub does not have these settings.

[image: Logitech C922 Pro webcam properties]

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool to save cam settings in profiles and restore from them. It's called CamooZ.

Find all details here:

https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/camooz-save-restore-cam-settings-local-and-remote.1271/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).